# Только начал изучать создание ботов в телеграмм, нужно чтобы после текста 'Перезапуск бота' снова открывалось изначальное меню с кнопками

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
from telebot import*

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

amount = 0
currency = CurrencyConverter()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Список команд')
    markup.row(btn1)
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Посчитать стоимость товара')
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Перезапуск бота')
    markup.row(btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Привет, выбери нужное действие</b>', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, on_click)

def on_click(message):
    if message.text == 'Список команд':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вот основной список команд')
    if message.text == 'Перезапуск бота': \\здесь возникает ошибка
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, start)
```

Comment: Небольшой совет в создании ботов для телеграмм лучше использовать aiogram, т.к это асинхронная библиотека, которая позволит вам обрабатывать несколько запросов от разных пользователей одновременно

Comment: If, elif используй

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!